# Lists in validation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a validation of a form in Laravel.

In this form I have two inputs (one text and one checkbox).

But I have two lists, in which I can move the elements from one list to another and order them.

But I don't know how to send these lists through the form to the Laravel validation.

Thanks in advance

My form:

```
<form id="create-menu-opac" action="{{ route('post_create_menu_opac')}}" method="post" role="form"  autocomplete="off">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   ...
<section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h6>{{ trans('menu-opac.buttons_avaiable') }}</h6>
         <ul id="buttons_no_selected" class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connected">
             @foreach ($buttons as $button)
                  <li id="{{$button->id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">{{$button->description}}</li>
               @endforeach
          </ul>
     </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <h6>{{ trans('menu-opac.items_menu') }}</h6>
        <ul id="buttons_selected" class="list-group list-group-sortable-connected connected">
        </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
</section>
...
</form>
```

This two lists work with a library Jquery and Boostrap

My controller

```
foreach ($request as $_request) {
        Log::Debug(print_r($_request,true));
    }
```

In this Log I can see the two inputs (type text and type checkbox), but i can't see the list.

Comment: if you want to validate in the controller you can use `$request->validate(["YourFieldName" => "required", "YourFieldEmail" => "required|unique"])`

Comment: Correct but my problem is that I don't know how to send a list from the view to the controller.

Comment: Could you include your form in your `blade` file, when you want to send something to the controller usually it goes through a form method

Comment: You mean `name="list[]"` ?

Comment: The list have an id, but this id not appear in the request in php controller

Comment: The connection to php works fine. The problem is in my request. Do not have the list in her inputs.

Comment: can you show me your controller? wait in your blade there's no `input` tag?

Comment: Yes, but how can i put a input tag in a sorted list

Comment: I made an answer about the `input` tag, could you try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `input hidden` in your `blade` file then see if you get the data in your `$request`

```
@foreach ($buttons as $button)
     <li id="{{$button->id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">{{$button->description}}</li>
     <input type="hidden" id="{{$button->id}}" value="{{$button->description}}" name="{{$button->description}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: do not apear the inputs in the controller

Comment: I change it a bit try it now?

Comment: if I put <input type="hidden" id="{{$button->id}}" name="{{$button->id}}" value="{{$button->description}}"> appears

Comment: but this i can not sort

Comment: by sort, do you mean you want to sort the list (the list in @foreach)? if yes could you send the `Log::Debug(print_r($_request,true));` output I think I can do something about it

Comment: I use this https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Drag-drop-Sorting-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-html5sortable/ to sort

Comment: It's your problem. MamaWin answer has solved your first problem. You should mark this answer as accepted if its work. Now go solve your next problem.

Comment: since its on the controller it use Laravel and you will need to manually sort it